# How do I add a space every 3 characters of a string, but only until the 12th character?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a certain set of characters in a cell, for example `+ab123456789cdefgh...`

and I want the formula to add a space every 3 characters up until the 12th character.

the result would be like so: `+ab 123 456 789 cdefgh...`

I tried using `=REGEXREPLACE("string",".{3}", "$0 ")` but of course it works for the whole string.

What could I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string at the 12th character. Add space in the first part of the string using regex. Concatenate the string after regex and the second part of the string. You may have to check the length of the input string too.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use capture groups like this:

`=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE("+ab123456789cdefgh"&REPT(" ",12),"(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})(.*)","$1 $2 $3 $4 $5"))`

I've appended 12 spaces with `REPT(" ",12)` and wrapped the result in `TRIM( )` as a failsafe, in case some string has fewer than 12 overall characters in the original. This will allow the intended return through as many characters as exist instead of returning just the original string if it were shorter than 12 characters (having found nothing that matched the REGEX sequence). In other words, with the appended spaces, it will *always* find the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,MID(A1,{1,4,7,10},3),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(12,LEN(A1)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1,REPT("(.{3})",12/3),JOIN(,"$"&SEQUENCE(12/3)&" ")))
```

- `REPT` the capture group `(.{3})` (number of characters to stop)/(number of characters in each group) 12/3 times
- Create a `SEQUENCE` of `$1 $2 ..` as replacement string